# Set ImageView's visibility (programmatically) before setContentView - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, setcontentview

I don't like editing elements' XML attributes, so I prefer doing it programmatically. Is there any alternative to setting an `ImageView`'s visibility to `INVISIBLE` and changing it back to `VISIBLE` in the Java code? Is there any way I can do both programmatically, i.e., set the `ImageView`'s visibility to `INVISIBLE` and make it visible again using Java code? I guess it won't work the usual way as such code can be used only after `setContentView()`. For example, I might want to process the image and then display it rather than display it and then process it, etc. So, if I want to do something like that, which can be achieved only programmatically, and only after `setContentView()`, how should I go about it?

Comment: "Is there any way I can do both programmatically, i.e., set the ImageView's visibility to INVISIBLE and make it visible again using Java code?" -- in your preceding sentence, you indicated that you did not want to do this. You might want to edit your question and explain in detail what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I'd also get used to editing XML- you sometimes need to change things at runtime,a nd that's fine.  But you'll find all your code reviews getting rejected if you're setting everything in code when you don't have to, nobody programs that way because its FAR less readable.

Comment: @GabeSechan, what if that's the only way? I've come across this thought many times, and I'm stuck. And yes, I do agree that it's less readable and unnecessary, etc.

Comment: @EEE If it needs to be done at runtime, sure.  Do it in Java (that is the only way).  If its an initial condition it should be done in xml though.  I'm not sure what you're really asking here though-  are you just having trouble using findViewById and calling a function on the view?

Comment: @GabeSechan, no, not really. I can set the visibility in the XML, but what about something like loading a website in a `WebView`, clicking a button, entering something, etc., and then showing the `WebView`? And I don't really like using `LayoutInflater` as I've tried using it before; I couldn't figure out how to use it. And when I'd tried inflating a `WebView`, I couldn't do much with it easily. Is there any other way to do it in Java? I'm asking how you can process elements/views in the Java code before showing them (before `setContentView`).

Comment: This question does not make any sense at all. At the end of the day, you still need views either stock views and custom ones. `setContentView()` requires either a resource id or a view. `ImageView` is a view, `Button` is a view. Heck, you can just pass `setContentView(new View(this));` if you want to.

Comment: @Darkman, why? And no, that's not what I'm trying to do. I guess it'd make sense if you reread it.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible. Instead, you can use the myLayout.xml file for default values. then, after setContentView() you can change that as you want using:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It is not possible because setContentView() binds the class with their layout and run it to give the default values, then you can override the default values using the code above.

---

One way to play around that is using LayoutInflater like the code below:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null,false);
```

But you will end up with the same result (with a lot more of code), and yet you need to bind the class with their layout and set their content view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way other than using `LayoutInflater`? Or can you please explain, for example, how I should inflate an `ImageView` so that I can, for example, use an external (Java) library to process the image (at runtime) and then show it? And what exactly do you mean by inflating a view/layout? Will you get a duplicate of the view/layout, and can I process that (in the Java code), and then while showing the main layout (not inflated? or should that be, too?), can I replace the real view (eg: ImageView) with the processed and inflated view (before `setContentView`)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what the whole purpose of doing that. LayoutInflater is used generally in recyclerView, fragments... I think you can achieve your goal by learning more about fragments and how to use them. 
- (what will be inflated is the layout, not the ImageView. then from the object view you get findViewByID() and here you could find your imageView) - and your will end up using setContentView()